# Is it possible to programatically interrogate the fields of a screen (selection screen) of a given program in order to get their types?

Tags: reflection, abap, dynpro

I have a list of programs whose selection screens variants I would like to check for hardcoded values of parameters of type `BUKRS`.

The function module `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS` does almost all of the job, in that for a given variant and program, it returns a list of the values filled in that variant.

Unfortunately it doesn't return the types of those parameters, only their values. Thus I figure I need an additional check, namely for the type of the parameter defined in the screen.

Now I realize that the keyword `PARAMETERS` defines both a screen field and a data object in the current program, the type of either of those would be of great help (being obviously the same). This is of course in the happy case where I even have a `PARAMETERS` data object defined, and not a `SELECT-OPTIONS`.

I have also come across function module `DYNPRO_FIELD_GET` which gives me the screen fields, as defined in the selection screen, but again, no help with the types.... So yeah, any help would be appreciated.

I have even found a FuBa called `GET_DICTIONARY_FIELDS` which promised to give me exactly what i wanted: a list of all the variables in a program, which I could then corroborate with the list given by `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS` to get the information I wanted - unfortunately in the version of my system, it's inactive.

**[EDIT]**

It should be noted that `RS_SELSCREEN_INFO` returns the types of the data objects as defined in the program with their respective statements. For example for:

```
DATA gv_asdfg TYPE mara-matnr.
```

it returns `MARA-MATNR`. Of course the name of the table field is no indication of the name of the data element, so:

In order to get the domain for these types one could use `CL_ABAP_DATADESCR=>DESCRIBE_BY_NAME( )` and provide the types given by `RS_SELSCREEN_INFO`. For the resulting object, the property one should look for is `->ABSOLUTE_NAME`. In my case, the condition is `...->ABSOLUTE_NAME = '\TYPE=BUKRS'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the function module `RS_SELSCREEN_INFO`. Given a report name, it will return a list of the parameters and select options along with the DDIC reference information, if set.

Answer (score 0):

Althouth vwegert's answer actually did the complete trick, i've also found 2 function modules that help a lot.

These are **GET_GLOBAL_SYMBOLS** - this returns the global variables of a program. It works for variables defined by `DATA` and `PARAMETERS` but it fails to work for `SELECT-OPTIONS`.

The other one is **GET_COMPONENT_LIST** - this could be used to get the elementary data types of the variables declared with `SELECT-OPTIONS`.